# If $AB$ is onto as a linear transformation, then so is $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like I should be using $T(x) = b$ for every $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ but im not sure how?

Comment: $T(X):R^n \to R^m$ ?

Comment: You should specify your spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B:U\to V$ and $A:V\to W$, and suppose that $AB:U\to W$ is onto, then for $w\in W$, there exists $u\in U$ such that $w=AB(u)=A(B(u))$. Take $v=B(u)\in V$ we have $w=A(v)$, and hence $A$ is onto.